# как рендерить сайт на php в nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, express

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const config = require('config')
const path = require('path')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const engine  = require( 'ejs-locals' )
const phpnode  = require( 'php' )

const app = express()
const PORT = 5001

async function start() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(config.get('mongoUri'), {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true
    })
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`App has been started on port ${PORT}...`))
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Server Error', e.message)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

start()


app.use('*', express.static(__dirname + '../../landing'));
app.use('/api/testRender', require('./routes/testRender.routes'))
```

**testRender.routes**

```
const {Router} = require('express')
const router = Router()

router.get('/layout', async (req, res) => {
  try {
  
    return await res.render(`../../landing/test.php`)

  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте снова' + e })
  }
})
```

Шаблон подгружается, но *картинки*, *стили* и *скрипты* - нет!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя **php** код отрабатывает

Как сделать это правильно?

Comment: `express.static` навешивается только если `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'`. для более вдумчивого анализа недостаточно данных

Comment: @nörbörnën похоже if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') не срабатывет

Comment: так может быть............ например, если process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'........ или потому что __dirname не то, что вы думаете

Comment: Ok я его тогда комментирую он тут не нужен

Comment: а кто будет таки отдавать статику?

Comment: @nörbörnën хороший вопрос но я не знаю точный ответ, думаю express через метод render

Comment: ты убрал код, который этим занимался раздачей статики. читай со слов "Сделать это используя express и express-static" ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1229233 и документацию https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/static-files.html

Comment: @nörbörnën добавил код , но у меня не заработало

Comment: @nörbörnën все ок, получилось, с путями напутал

Comment: хорошо_________